# получить скорость движения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте!
Двигаю шагающего перса вот этим:

```
  player.transform.position += player.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Естественно, сам задаю скорость. Шагающий перс упирается в коллайдер и останавливается, продолжая шагать.Как узнать о том, что он перестал двигаться, чтобы в зависимости от скорости изменить анимацию.
Кажется, я делаю недопустимо...

Comment: Сравнивайте предыдущие координаты с текущими. Если координаты не изменились, значит он не двигается.

Comment: Пробую, чет не получается пока

Comment: Ёмкий комментарий. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Можно у коллайдера повесить `OnTriggerEnter` или даже `OnCollisionEnter`.... и посмотреть если `tag` объекта, который в него врезался `Player`, то послать `SendMessage` в скрипт игрока...в метод..который отвечает за переключение анимации и пр

Comment: пробовал просто OnCollisionEnter. Ничего не выясняя, не получилось. Попробую по вашему совету

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` повесить можно даже на игрока.. и если объект с которым столкнулся = НужныйОбъект - то сделать то, что надо..... я просто немного спутал... `OnCollisionEnter` - вызывается когда ` collider/rigidbody` Данного объекта начинает соприкосаться с `rigidbody/collider` другого объекта..... а `OnTriggerEnter` - вызывается когда `Collider` другого объекта входит в триггер.......  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html  . так что тут можно обойтись будет даже без `SendMessage`

Comment: С этим разобрался. OnCollisionEnter  не работает. на другом коллайдере нет rigidbody. А если повесить, перестает rigidbody в него упираться. То же самое, если сделать его триггером.

Comment: Всё работает....Вы чуть не так сделали..... объясню.... игрок должен иметь Collider (box/circle/capsule) и rigidbody! и в скрипте повешанном на игроке написано что-то типа `void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            Debug.Log("Yo");
    }`.......... А вот на коллайдере... просто коллайдер (box например) и на нем не обязательно должен быть rigidbody

Comment: Решил внять советам на двигать rigidbody методом transform.position. Теперь движение такое:  player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += transform.forward * speed; Все равно игрок стоит, а скорость в инспекторе не нуль.

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей! Дествительно, лог выводит, почему то не делает ничего остального, прописанного. Буду разбираться,где накосячил.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете физику, а объект двигаете через изменение позиции в `transform.position` это совсем не хорошо, вы нарушаете работу PhysX. Либо надо использовать `CharacterController` с соответствующими методами, либо прикладывать к объекту силу для смещения. А скорость я бы считал запоминая последнюю позицию(lastPosition) в методе `FixedUpdate` до расчета физики, затем сравнивал позицию в `Update` между текущей и `lastPosition`, и если длина перемещения мала то просто останавливал бы персонажа.

Comment: вы правы. Мне подходит CharacterController. Я пытаюсь решать простые задачи  простыми методами. Использование  CharacterController не скажется отрицательно на производительности?

Comment: Проведите тесты, у большинства все работает шустро)